# How do I render an Html Code present in a PHP variable in an external website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP variable `$htmldocument` which contains an html code of a webpage as a string. ( Html Code can contains `scripts` `styles` and `htmls` ) The php variable is presented in `htmlfetch.php`

The sample of the html code is shown in *https://pastebin.com/ZSbKPz4s*

In the external website i have something like:

```
<div class="codehere"></div>
<script src="example.com/jsfile.js"></script>
```

How do I make that `jsfile.js` and render the html code from the PHP variable in the browser?
Or what should i do inorder to achieve this?